# How to query nested data in a REST API built with Prisma

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, prisma

I am building a REST API using `Express` and `Prisma`. I have a `Prisma` datamodel like below

```
type User {
  id: ID! @id
  email: String! @unique
  name: String
  posts: [Post!]! @relation(link: INLINE)
}

type Post {
  id: ID! @id
  createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
  updatedAt: DateTime! @updatedAt
  published: Boolean! @default(value: false)
  title: String!
  content: String
  author: User!
}
```

Now, if I query data like this

```
const posts = await prisma.users()
```

It returns me only the posts.

```
[
  {
    "id": "cjo5vwaaq6e7p0a42qpoz3aj3",
    "email": "ada@prisma.io",
    "name": "Ada"
  }
]
```

But I also want to get all the posts of a user inside the user Object.

```
[
    {
      "id": "cjo5vwaaq6e7p0a42qpoz3aj3",
      "email": "ada@prisma.io",
      "name": "Ada", 
      "posts": [
         {
            "title": "This is title"
         }
       ]
    }
]
```

How can I do this? I am new at `Prisma`. I know I don't have to use `Prisma` to build a REST API but here I've to. 
But I don't find any good documentation of Prisma to use with REST API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query relation data you need to use fragments or the prisma fluent API. As you already discovered the prisma client only returns scalar fields and no relations. Posts in your case are a relation.

> Whenever a database record is queried using the Prisma client, all
>   scalar fields of that record are fetched. This is true no matter if a
>   single record or a list of records is queried.

See: https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-client/basic-data-access/reading-data-JAVASCRIPT-rsc2

For single queries (e.g. getting a single user) you can use the prisma fluent API. So in your case to get the posts by a certain user you can write:

```
const posts = await prisma.user({ where: { email: 'test@test.de' }})).posts()
```

See: https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-client/basic-data-access/reading-data-JAVASCRIPT-rsc2/#relations

This is only possible for single records, not for lists. To retrieve data for all records you need to use fragments. E.g. to get relational post data alongside the user data you can write something like:

```
const fragment = `
  fragment UserWithPosts on User {
    id
    name
    email
    posts {
      id
      title
    }
  }
`

const userWithPosts = await prisma.users().$fragment(fragment)
```

See: https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-client/basic-data-access/reading-data-JAVASCRIPT-rsc2/#selecting-fields

Hope that helped.